# trying to sum a list of key value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a dumb little coding challenge that has me stumped. I am trying to take a list of key value pairs like such:

John: 2

Jane: 3

John: 4

Jane: 5

Your objective is to sum the counts for each key in the textarea, and display the totals for each

key within the HTML document. The default value should result in the output, "The total for

John is 6. The total for Jane is 8."

I am trying to do this with no jquery or any other framework Here is what I have so far and I keep getting NaN for the value. I maybe have my logic reversed?

```
$(function() {
var keyStore = document.getElementById("keyValPairs");

if (!keyStore){
    alert("you suck DIE!!!!!");
}
var hashTable = {};

var str = split(",");
for( var entry in str){

    var a = entry.split(":")
    if(!hashTable.hasOwnProperty(a[0])){
        hashTable[a[0]] = 0;
    }
    hashTable[a[0]] += parseInt(a[1]);
}

console.log(obj);

});
```

I used the jquery function to wrap it because I don"t remember what the regular way of saying when the dom is loaded.

Html:

```
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel panel-header">
    <h1>Sum up your key value pairs</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <textarea class="preescreen-input" name="keyValPairs" id="keyValPairs" cols="30" rows="10">
        John : 2,
        Jane: 3,
        John : 4,
        Jane : 5,
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sum</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            Insert
        </button></br></br>
        <label for="inputBoxKey">Enter Key</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputBoxKey" name="inputBoxKey"></br></br>
        <label for="inputBoxVal">Enter Value</label>
        <input type=" text" id=inputBoxVal name="inputBoxVal">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-offset-4 panel panel-footer">
        <input type="text ">
    </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Its just a stupid little programming challenge that I found online but none the less It has me perplexed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're calling `split(",")` without giving it a string to split on
2. when you do `for( var entry in str)`, `entry` is the key, not the value of the entry in`str`
3. You need to bind the sum button to a function to run the code
4. You should trim your strings to remove whitespace
5. You should make sure names are valid and bail if not (to deal with blank lines)

Here's your code with these changes:

```
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel panel-header">
    <h1>Sum up your key value pairs</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <textarea class="preescreen-input" name="keyValPairs" id="keyValPairs" cols="30" rows="10">
        John : 2,
        Jane: 3,
        John : 4,
        Jane : 5,
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sum()">Sum</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            Insert
        </button></br></br>
        <label for="inputBoxKey">Enter Key</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputBoxKey" name="inputBoxKey"></br></br>
        <label for="inputBoxVal">Enter Value</label>
        <input type=" text" id=inputBoxVal name="inputBoxVal">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-offset-4 panel panel-footer">
        <input type="text ">
    </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

and js:

```
window.sum = function() {
    var keyStore = document.getElementById("keyValPairs");

    if (!keyStore){
        alert("you suck DIE!!!!!");
    }
    var hashTable = {};

    var str = keyStore.value.split(",");
    for( var key in str){
        var entry = str[key].trim();
        var a = entry.split(":");
        if(a.length > 0) a[0] = a[0].trim();
        if(a.length > 1) a[1] = a[1].trim();
        if(a[0] == '') continue;
        if(!hashTable.hasOwnProperty(a[0])){
            hashTable[a[0]]=0;
        }
        hashTable[a[0]]+=parseInt(a[1]);
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(hashTable));
}
```

Comment: that helps thank you, I still am getting Nan in wired places see console log
Object {"                    John": 2, "↵                    Jane: 3": NaN, "↵                    John": 4, "↵                    Jane": 5, "↵                ": NaN}

Comment: @Guyute see my edited code, I added `if(a[0] == '') continue;` and more trim calls. You always want to have safe checks like this when dealing with user input.